# Repeater with div eval ID data-target

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asprepeater

I am trying to change my data-target in my repeater div control using c# back end. the data-target points to a pop up modal. here is my front end code with the div I'm trying to control:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="col-lg-4" id="repeaterDiv" runat="server" data-toggle="modal" 
             data-target='#<%#Eval("FoodID")%>'>
```

---

In the aspx.cs, I want to change the *data-target* to `'#<%# Eval("FoodID2")%>'`:

```
HtmlGenericControl repeaterLabel = Rptitem.FindControl("repeaterDiv") as 
HtmlGenericControl;
String newLabelAttribute = "'#<%# Eval(\"FoodID2\")%>'";
repeaterLabel.Attributes.Add("data-target", newLabelAttribute);
```

The problem is that I can't access the repeater control `repeaterDiv` unless I put a `runat="Server"` in the div, but then the *data-target* doesn't work when I do that.

How I can solve above?

Comment: Is you're changing it in OnClikck?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
String newLabelAttribute = "'#<%# Eval(\"FoodID2\")%>'";
```

and use this:

```
String newLabelAttribute = string.format("'#{0}'", FoodID2.ClientID);
```